# How to connect A2DP from mobile to sink device programmatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I have to connect A2DP from mobile to a sink device programmatically on android 2.3.3

I know a Mac address and a name of the sink device and I am going to use them.

But I could not find any apis to do that.

Comment: If anyone has any information on how to achieve this in later versions of Android (4.2+) too, I'd be hugely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665703/how-write-a-program-to-connect-to-a-a2dp-bluetooth-device-using-pre-3-0-android)
Actually this API is hidden. So need to remove that annotation and customize android.jar.
Then you can call connectSink(). Any ways mentioned link is having useful detail for this.